# String with special chars from Ajax POST to DB insert

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

i have a form with some text inputs, then i have an ajax event to send this value via POST to my database php script, the issue is that i dont know how to send special chars from my ajax event, if the string has ' " \ or similar chars, it wont insert data to my database, but if the string only contains Numbers/Letters and no special chars...i can insert the data without a problem.

Ajax event

```
$$("#message").click(function(e) {
                var nick_ = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
                var message_ = $.trim(($("#msgtext").val()).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""));

                if (message_ .length>0 && message_ .length<=500) 

                 $.ajax({type: "POST", 
                        url: "insert.php",
                        data: ({nick: nick_, mensaje: message_ }),
                      cache: false,
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(data) {
                  if(data.status == 'success'){
                       $('input[type=text], textarea').val('');   
                   } 
                }});

                else myApp.alert('Min:1 Max:500','Chars:');             

            });
```

And this is my database script

```
<?php

//jSON
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');
//Connect to DB
include('con.php');

//POST vars
$nick=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nick']));
$message=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mensaje']));
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//DB insert
$mysqli->real_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('0','$nick','$message','$date')");

if ($mysqli) $response_array['status'] = 'success';
       else              
             $response_array['status'] = 'error';

    echo json_encode($response_array);

?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that if your POST has  `' " \`, it won't add it to the db?

Answer (score 0):

before sending your data (`{nick: nick_, mensaje: message_ }`) in ajax, you can verify it using:

```
function isValid(data){
   for (i in data){
      if(!data[i].match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/))
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

use it like:

```
isValid({nick: nick_, mensaje: message_ })
```

this will return true if the data is either letter or character, and false otherwise.

Moreover, you should not be relying on any client side script for this kind of validation.

Comment: the issue is that i cant send my string to my php script if the string has special chars like ' | \

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your php script. Try this

```
  $v = trim($_POST['mensaje']);
  $message = htmlspecialchars($conn->escape_string($v));
```

All i did is to escape the post value.

And also the way you are checking if your query was sucessfull should be changed.  you are checking the conn object instead of catching a return boolean value from the $conn->real_query () which should give you the real outcome of your query processing (True of false).

```
    $result = $conn->real_query("........);

    if ($result){
        //do something
    }else{
       echo $conn->error;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form you can try `data:$(this).serializeArray()` which escapes those characters

OR

You can use an editor which I would recommend something like tinyMCE.